# pycharm ssh interpter No such file or directory

Tags: python, ssh, pycharm

I am using a macbook pro 15 as local machine and I have a remote server running ubuntu 14.04

I want to use the remote intepreter to run all the computation but I want to write the code from my local machine.

When I try to run a simple file with pycharm I receive this error:

```
ssh://donbeo@149.157.140.205:22/usr/bin/python3 -u /Users/donbeo/Documents/phd_code/prova.py
bash: line 0: cd: /Users/donbeo/Documents/phd_code: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/python3: can't open file '/Users/donbeo/Documents/phd_code/prova.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Process finished with exit code 2
```

I saw few people reporting the same problem but I haven't found a good answer so far. Most of the questions are indeed referring to older versions of pycharm.

It is clear that the file is not in my remote machine because I create it with pycharm in my local one. I was expecting pycharm to do some sort of synchronisation between the local and remote machine.

Comment: You have to define deployment settings and remote interpreter for your project. And, of course, deploy your code before execution. I'll post detailed answer in the evening (if no one posts it here before me).

Comment: That's under Tools, then Deployment, then Configuration.

Comment: what `type` should I use `FTP`?

Comment: FTP should be specifically configured. More often ssh includes scp or sftp.

Comment: but there is not ssh.  5 options: ftp, ftps, sftp, local or mounted folder, inplace

Comment: I suppose the right one is sftp. I have filled the mapping fields as well but I am still getting the same error. The file is syncronized in the remote machine as I can see it but pycharm still tries to run it using my local path

Comment: @Donbeo feel free to ask questions if any point would require clarification.

Comment: @Donbeo, were you finally able to figure out the answer didn't work for me at all.ll. After ssh connection, it always posts an error that it can't find the directory even though it was visible in the PYCHARM IDE

Comment: @Donbeo Hi, 'Users/donbeo/Documents/phd_code/prova.py' is in your remote server right?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

To execute your code on remote machine you'll have to perform few steps

## Define a remote interpreter for your project

1. Go to File -> Settings -> Project: {project_name} -> Project Interpreter.
2. Click on cog icon and select Add Remote.
3. Add your SSH host credentials and interpreter path (on remote machine).
4. As a result, you should see new position in project interpreter dropdown selector, spelled like `Python Version (ssh://login@host:port/path/to/interpreter)`. Package list should be populated with records.

## Define deployment settings

1. Go to File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Deployment
2. Create new deployment settings and fill ssh host configuration

   - Type: SFTP
   - SFTP host: same as interpreter host
   - Root path: path where files will be uploaded
3. Click on button "Test SFTP connection" to check if provided data are correct.
4. Go to mappings and configure mapping between local path and deployment path. **Deployment path is relative to root path** - `/` is equivalent to `/my/root/path`, `/dir` to `/my/root/path/dir` etc.

## Deploy your code

1. Select Tools -> Deployment -> Upload to {deployment settings name}
2. Upload process will be started in background. Wait for upload to complete.

## Run your code

1. Right click on file you want to run and select "Run". Code should run on remote machine.

Comment: I think my problems are related to mapping. These are my values: `local path :/Users/donbeo/Documents/phd_code`  `deployement path:/home/donbeo/Documents/phd_code/` `web path:/home/donbeo/Documents/phd_code/` but despite that I still get the error `/usr/bin/python3: can't open file '/Users/donbeo/Documents/phd_code/prova.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: @Donbeo What is your root path in Deployment -> Connection?

Comment: `/home/donbeo` should I change it to something else? I used the autodetect button

Comment: If your root path is `/home/donbeo`, mapping deployment path should be relative to this path, `/` is equivalent to `/home/donbeo`, so correct path is `/Documents/phd_code`.

Comment: I have always the same error. I think it is not reading the mapping.

Comment: in this tutorial http://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2010/12/python-remote-debug-with-pycharm/ they have a box with written `use path mapping` I am wondering if I should use something like that to activate the mapping. Unfortunately I can not find any `active map` button

Comment: I have solved. In `run-> edit configurations -> path mappings` I wrote `/Users/donbeo/Documents=/home/donbeo/Documents`

Comment: Does anyone know how to combine these two steps, so that when you click `Run`, it will automatically deploy first?

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski, I followed your post line by line, but My 
"ssh://ubuntu@ec2-52-41-247-169.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:22/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/bin/python -u <08ad9807-3477-4916-96ce-ba6155e3ff4c>/home/ubuntu/InsightProject/scripts/download_flownet2.py
/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/bin/python: can't open file '<08ad9807-3477-4916-96ce-ba6155e3ff4c>/home/ubuntu/InsightProject/scripts/download_flownet2.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory" error doesn't get eleminated at all.

Comment: You will know it works when you see the 1st line of the run console something like this `sudo+ssh://noams@35.203.158.138:22/home/noams/hopenet/venv/bin/python3 -u /home/noams/hopenet/deep-head-pose/code/Utils/create_filename_list.py` instead of `sudo+ssh://noams@35.203.158.138:22/home/noams/hopenet/venv/bin/python3 -u SOME/LOCAL/PATH/Utils/create_filename_list.py`

Answer (score 15):

Sometimes you can have everything set up correctly (interpreter, deployment, Path mapping, etc) but PyCharm keeps trying to use your local path on the **remote machine**.

If this happens, try this 4 fixes:

1. Go to `File->Invalid Caches / Restart`

...if the problem is still not fixed:

2. Go to `Preferences->Python Interpreter->Path Mappings` and check the *path mappings* of the interpreter. They should look more or less like this:

[image: SSH Path Mappings]

...again, if the previous step didn't work:

3. Go to `Run->Edit Configurations...` and check if the path mappings are correct:

[image: PyCharm Path Mappings Run/Debug]

4. You can also try to replace the local paths of the *script* and *working directory* with the remote ones (as if you were already in that machine).

[image: pycharm ssh interpreter paths]

5. If you get `ModuleNotFoundError` but the connection seems to work, go to `Run->Edit Configurations...->Environment Variables` and add your project's root path to the `PYTHONPATH` variable.

Comment: Yes! Adding Path mappings manually (under Run->Edit Configurations...) worked for me! However, when I closed and then reopened PyCharm, I again had the same issue. I solved it by just saving the file again (which triggered the file transfer to the remote machine).

Answer (score 5):

Be sure your interpreter is chosen as **SSH** which is to compile, not **STFP** which is for deployment.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I'm running `PyCharm 2018.3`

### The Problem:

First, I didn't have the `[Errno 2] No such file or directory` problem. Then I had the problem out of nowhere.

The issue arose when I did:

- Preferences -> Project: {project_name} -> Project Interpreter
- Instead of "Click on cog icon and select Add Remote", I chose a interpreter that I've configured previously (that is working fine previously) from the drop down menu

By doing the steps above, I had `[Errno 2] No such file or directory` problem.

The reason is that the folder is not automatically synced to the remote server (a bug?), nor could I find a way to configure it to sync. Configuring `Deployment` and `Path Mappings` did work, but it's too much manual labor and prone to error.

### The solution:

All I had to do is to add a new remote interpreter, despite that identical configurations already exists previously. (To be safe, I did remove the old ssh interpreter and the old deployments, also removed .idea folder) Then everything worked as expected.

- I didn't need to configure Deployment
- I didn't need to configure Paths mappings

Comment: This solves my problem! Just delete old one and add a new SSH intepreter!

Answer (score 0):

It can be caused by one of the following:

### 1. You did not deploy your code on the remote server.!

- Make sure that the recent edition of your code is deployed on the server. You can always deploy your code from Tools -> Deployment -> Upload to ..., or by using Ctrl + Shift + Alt + x.
- For setting the deployment path, Go to File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Deployment, and enter a remote sever details as your deploying machine.
- In the Mappings tab, make sure that the deployment path is defined somewhere on the server where you have permission to read and edit files there.

### 2. You do not have the permission to read and change files on your deployment path at the remote server.

- Go back to File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Deployment, and change deployment path on the Mappings tab.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, I am using Windows.

I needed to configure manually SSH Terminal and SSH Configuration. Only then I was able to run program as script.

Before that, I was able to run program in REPL mode.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

For those who meet the problem like "miniconda3/envs/gpu/bin/python: can't open file '///home/.../test.py", you can just run the python script file in locality in pycharm rather than run the file in server in pycharm.